# PHP add require command to all file in my site

Tags: php, require

I have a file `update.php` that it do some work on my server, such as add visitor ip to the mysql record, delete record expired after 5 minutes (to count user online), etc...
So in my index.php file I must call this file by php command:

```
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/update.php");
```

But with another file that user can access, I must insert this to work, and very much file in sub-folder,...
Can I config my server to do this automatic when the user access any file?

Or any other solution with this?
Thanks

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking but from what I gather, the two ways I'd tackle this is either making a template file that has it and copy it every time I want to do work or use some sort of package manager that could handle dependencies.

Comment: seems `auto_prepend_file` in php.ini